# Output location of project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was looking for the output of a project as a `*.dll` file to add it in `References`, but in `bin` folder there where `Release` and `Debug` folders.

**Is there any difrence between the `output.dll`s?**

**Where is the useable output?**

please explain the folders roles.

Comment: Along the toolbar, there's a combo box with things like "Debug" and "Release."  That setting decides which version to build (debug has symbols you use when stepping through code) and which folder to put it in. You'd be better off using a reference to the _project_ that generates the library.

Comment: If the consumer of the DLL is in the same solution, you should select the DLL by Project and not by Browsing. It then handles it correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a specific development environment, probably Visual Studio. Because your question doesn't really deal with any code, I would recommend looking at programmers.stackexchange.com. But @JohnC is right, the Debug output contains the symbols for stepping through your code.

Comment: @StephenH questions do not need to be dealing with code, but can also be about using software or tools that are directly related to software development, as mentioned in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @crashmstr, thanks for the heads up on that, my apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folders correspond to your *Solution Configurations*, e.g. *Debug* or *Release*. You can specify custom configurations as well, and a folder would be created for it.

Instead of referencing the .DLL file directly by browsing to it, you should reference the *project* that defines the .DLL. If the project is not in your solution, you can add it by right-clicking on the solution title in the Solution Explorer and choose "Add" > "Existing project...".

This will allow Visual Studio to rebuild the .DLL in case you make changes, which you can now make without leaving your other project, and automatically reference the correct version, and also reference the configuration matching your project, i.e. if your project is run in *Release*, it will also use the release version of the .DLL.